# XPATH: Get row number of a query in RobotFramework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

See code

https://prnt.sc/fscdi5

I want to get the row number containing the specific date string and the String TestTraining..

I can then use this to go to the Download Certificate link to click the correct link.

Comment: please don't link to a picture of code on another site. Take the time to embed the actual code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

to get row by any containing text:

```
//*[contains(text(),'someText')]/preceding::tr[1]
```

actually you can find any `tr` part by any attribute and use found `locator` to get it's row:

```
locator/preceding::tr[1]
```

Comment: This seems to only get the first row regardless of what i put into the text (as long as the text is contained in any row)